# Elastic Beanstalk Platform Create fails to create due missing easy_istall. How to solve?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a custom Elastic Beanstalk platform using Ubuntu. I am following the link below.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html#custom-platform-creating

But when i try to run the "eb platform create" command, it fails after sometime.I looked at the logs and noticed an error saying easy_install: command not found. Please note the relevant portions of the log. How do i fix this issue? Can any of you help?

[2019-03-19T16:44:27.915989+0000#3082]  INFO -- Packer: 1553013867,,ui,message,    HVM AMI builder: Setting up python-boto (2.44.0-1ubuntu2.18.04.0) ...
I, [2019-03-19T16:44:29.530448+0000#3082]  INFO -- Packer: 1553013869,,ui,message,    HVM AMI builder: + easy_install pip
I, [2019-03-19T16:44:29.531032+0000#3082]  INFO -- Packer: 1553013869,,ui,message,    HVM AMI builder: /tmp/script_8201.sh: line 107: **easy_install: command not found**
I, [2019-03-19T16:44:29.532812+0000#3082]  INFO -- Packer: 1553013869,,ui,say,==> HVM AMI builder: Terminating the source AWS instance...
I, [2019-0

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is the fact that `easy_install` was kicked out of the `python-setuptools` package from version `39.0.1-2` (see [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-setuptools/39.0.1-2)) but the `flavor: ubuntu1604` in the `platform.yaml` file still causes the packer to try to run the installation scripts the way it was for Ubuntu 16.04 (with `python-setuptools 20.7.0-1`).